# How can I find specific variables have the same names for all countries in original dataset and select them for another new dataset?

Tags: r

In R, I want to create data frame that has only specific variables. These variables carry the same name for each country. In the dataset there are many variables for each country. I want to ask R to find variables that carry XY name and add it to new date frame. So, how would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

We can use `grep` to find the pattern `"XY"` in the column names of the dataset.  It is not clear whether it is at the start or end.  But, in general, it should work

```
df2 <- df1[grep("XY", colnames(df1))]
```